# Alien embryos fall into a pond, turn into humans

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I read this book in 1996, it's a kids or young adult novel. Alien embryos fall from the sky into a pond on a family's property. They turn into pigs or pig like animals and then into humans. They act like feral children but then quickly develop into civilized humans, and they have special powers like telekinesis I think. I think it was a male and a female. They marry into the family and have children, and their children have special powers. I think the title had the word Star in it but I'm not sure. Also by the end one of the aliens, the man, is an old scientist or something. I just wish I could remember because I was fascinated with this book as a kid. Thanks for reading and hopefully someone knows what this book is, it's been bugging me for years now haha.

Comment: This isn't going to be helpful, but I do know of the book which you're talking about (and I can't remember the name either). I read it in about 1998 and from memory it's told from the perspective of the son of the family that finds the children. Not sure if this will help, but there's a scene in the book where the narrator overhears this alien boy telling his sister that they can't be together because he's growing older and older by the day, so by the time she comes of age he'll be an old man. Then he marries the older sister and has a daughter who is describe as being 'hardy' (she falls...

Comment: ...out of a tree from a great height and instead of screaming and crying like a normal girl, she brushes herself off and goes back to playing with her friends). And the alien boy does have amazing powers, but they exhaust him (I remember a bit where I think the kids were in trouble, like they were being threatened or there was an accident(??) and the alien child uses his amazing abilities to help them but it makes him really sick). Or it's possible we're thinking of two very similar but not quite the same books.

Comment: This isn't it, but I'm reminded of _Zogg_.  http://www.whatisdeepfried.com/zogg/zogg1.html.

Answer (score 4):

This may be Born Into Light by Paul Samuel Jacobs

Editorial Reviews from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0590406221)

> From Publishers Weekly
>
> Told in the first-person, this old-fashioned science fiction novel looks back upon the childhood of an old scientist. The narrator has puzzled over certain events for more than seven decades, events set into motion one morning when he was 10. A child appears out of a flash of light in their backyard and, believed to be feral or abandoned, is taken in by his family. But, before long, the child, Ben, reveals extraordinary intelligence and development. He matures quickly, finishes college in two years and ages much quicker than the narrator. The narrator's stepfather begins to investigate the other children who appeared on Earth in the same mysterious fashion as Ben; an alien race has seeded the human population with some of their own, strengthening their bloodlines and stimulating human progress. Ben gathers together as many of the aliens and their half-human offspring as he can find, and, in a flash of light, they return to the stars. While this is not a revolutionary novel, its themes of otherworldliness and superhumans will still appeal to SF fans. Ages 12-up.
>   Copyright 1988 Reed Business Information, Inc. *--This text refers to an out of print or unavailable edition of this title.*
>
> From School Library Journal
>
> Grade 6-10 This science fiction period piece depicts a quiet New England community near the turn of the century as it is visited and changed by a handful of strange un earthly beings, one of whom is taken in by the Westwood family and becomes young Roger's Westwood's brother. Considered at first to be feral children , they soon astonish their foster families by the extreme rapidity with which they learn language and customs and by their unusual recuperative powers after injury. Roger's foster brother eventually marries Roger's sister, produces children who seem to share the unique qualities of the strangers, and be gins a grand quest to track down and re unite all the alien visitors who have appeared throughout the United States in an effort to piece together the puzzle of their purpose on Earth. Jacobs' formal poetic style is appropriate for the time period. The story unfolds through the eyes of elderly Roger Westwood. Although this technique of an adult looking back on childhood events may limit the book's accessibility for some readers, the vividly visual language makes the novel a very finely crafted work. Gradual revelations about the nature of these beings and their origin should tantalize and beguile readers, and with its fascinating plot, the book should appeal to many. Lyle Blake Smythers, Library of Congress, Washington, D.C.
>   Copyright 1988 Reed Business Information, Inc. *--This text refers to an out of print or unavailable edition of this title.*

Comment: Welcome to scifi. Can you edit your answer  and include why you think this may be what the question is asking for?. e,g, what about that story matches the question.  Also highlight what does not match.